# Display ♥ correctly in php

Tags: php, html, json, simplexml

I am using php to dynamically display a page. However, it does not display correctly on some characters, for example ♥. I am getting the JSON string using SimpleXML. When I do `echo $string`, it returns `Ã¢ÂÂ¥`. Then, I tried using `utf8_decode($string)`, and I got `â¥`, which is still wrong. How do I manipulate this string correctly for it to display `♥` when I write `echo $string`?

Comment: maybe setting `UTF-8` might help?

Comment: the original XML doc is in UTF-8. Would I still need to set it?

Comment: try setting `UTF-8` for the encoding of the html/php page.

Comment: +1 for spreading love!

Comment: `utf8_decode` is a really badly named function which is almost never what you want. What you actually want is to tell every part of your application that the string is already UTF-8, and not to interpret it as anything else.

Comment: I set UTF-8, made no difference. What now?

Comment: @IMSoP how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in the `<head>` of your PHP file:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

For HTML5 (thanks to scootergrisen), you can also use:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**Edit**:

Well, to me, it seems that your API is not encoding properly. This will make any attempts to decode your string fail (and leave you with parsing '♥' yourself).

Your API encodes ♥ as `\u00c3\u00a2\u00c2\u0099\u00c2\u00a5`, which according to [this](http://unicodelookup.com/#0x2665/1) seems invalid.

Therefore, the only (hackish) solution that I see right now would be to re-parse your API's response yourself, for example like [this](http://pastebin.com/uFMwfTEE).

**Edit 2**:

Whatever it is your API is doing, **don't rely on it**. You have all the data you need in your XML already (in an unescaped, UTF-8 format), so why not access it directly? :)

This might be the best thing to do without any hackish fixes:

```
$name = $steamdata->steamID;
```

Comment: Or this shorter version in your HTML5 file (if your using HTML5) : <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: Well, you could save an extra two characters by just writing:
`<meta charset=utf-8>`, since HTML5 treats quotes as optional. :)

Comment: Please don't omit the quotes. It is horrible practice.

Comment: @Chiru, unfortunately, neither your solution, nor scootergrisen's solution worked. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: That's weird. What does the `Content-Type` section of your server's HTTP header say? You can find out with `curl -sIL example.com | grep "Content-Type"`. In this section, you can force the server to use a specific charset. You might want to set it to `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`, which needs to be done in your webserver's configuration.

Comment: @Chiru, This is what it returned: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. Anything else I can try to do to fix the problem?

Comment: This looks perfect! Does "♥" display in a new file on your server that looks like this? http://pastebin.com/wEPw6rvd If not, will it display for a new file that looks like this? http://pastebin.com/4J6wzhfG

Comment: @Chiru, seems like your edited answer will work. Haven't tried yet, for one reason. I have to have the code for any usernames the user decides to throw at it, and I can't have a line for every single incorrectly encoded character. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: Alright, I see. The only way to resolve this for all Unicode characters would be to find out if even all Unicode characters are affected by a wrong conversion function of the API (just try some other characters, for instance).

Other than that, you'd have to find out why the API thinks that `\u00c3\u00a2\u00c2\u0099\u00c2\u00a5` is an encoding for `♥` (maybe by comparing a few screw-ups and trying to find a pattern).

As far as I can tell, this error seems to happen on server-side (theirs), not yours. Best solution yet: Issue a ticket, this doesn't seem to be right! Have you seen it working?

Comment: @Chiru, yes! [This website](http://backpack.tf/id/swissolo) displays the name correctly... Anything else you could suggest? Thank you for persevering in helping me... I appreciate it. :)

Comment: @faeophyta Well, what do you think about this [this](http://pastebin.com/KtmJERV2)? :)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you save your file and present your file to the browser with the same encoding.
For example save your PHP file in `UTF-8` and add in your HTML5 file `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
```

If it still dont work it might be because your using some PHP functions that dont understand `multibyte` and thinks `8 bytes = 1 character`.

There are some replacement functions.
For example `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()` if you install the multibyte extionsion during the PHP installation.

But for some functions there is not a replacement but you can try and make one yourself.

I had problems with `ucfirst()` because there is no `mb_ucfirst()`.

So instead of this which gave me the same problem you have :

```
function mb_ucfirst($tekst){

   return utf8_encode(ucfirst(utf8_decode($tekst)));

}
```

I use this :

```
function my_mb_ucfirst($str){

    $fc = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1));

    return $fc . mb_substr($str, 1);

}
```

Maybe this can help you.
Try looking through your code that manipulates the string and disable the linies one by one until the problem changes.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I looked through the code, and I do no string manipulation. All I do is get it from XML using SimpleXML, like so: `$data = simplexml_load_file($file);` Then I do: `$name = $data->response->players[0]->name;` When I `echo $name`, it returns `Ã¢ÂÂ¥`. When I `echo mb_detect_encoding($name);`, it returns `UTF-8`. Do you have any idea of what I may be doing wrong? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What about your XML file is that also in UTF-8 and have you set the encoding in that file also : **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>**

Comment: here's the XML file in question: [XML file](http://steamcommunity.com/id/swissolo/?xml=1), XML doc is also in UTF8

Comment: The heart is inside **<![CDATA[** and **]]>**. Try **echo $name->asXML();**

Comment: nope, still doesn't work... prints `[Ã¢ÂÂ¥]swissolo`

Comment: Make a example somewhere with all the code. Also try another browser and check your browser settings. The browser might be set use another encoding manually.